# Trying to understand the MATHEMATICA integration solution

Tags: definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to understand the result of an integration obtained by using Mathematica software.

$P(y) = \int_0^{\infty}\Bigl[\Gamma(1+a)-\Gamma\bigl((1+a),\frac{\gamma_sy}{A\sigma^2_r}\bigr)\Bigr]y^k\exp\Bigl(-\frac{y}{B\sigma^2_e}\Bigr)\text{d}y$ ----(1)

where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Euler Gamma function and $\Gamma\bigl(\cdot,\cdot\bigr)$ is the upper incomplete Gamma function and $a,A,B,\sigma^2_r,\sigma^2_e,k$ all are constants.

The Mathematica solved the equation (1) as

$P = \Bigl(\frac{1}{B\sigma^2_e}\Bigr)^{-1-k}\Gamma(1+k)\Gamma(1+a)-\frac{\Bigl(\frac{\gamma_s}{A\sigma^2_r}\Bigr)^{-1-k}\Gamma(2+k+a)\text{Hypergeometric}_2F_1\Bigl(1+k,2+k+a,2+k,\frac{-A\sigma^2_{r}}{B\sigma^2_{e}\gamma_s}\Bigr)}{1+k}$ ----(2)

Where $\text{Hypergeometric}_2F_1(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Hypergeometric function.

I am not getting how eq.(2) is obtained by Mathematica from eq.(1).

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated...

Comment: Ok sir.... Thank you for you reply...I am posting the MATHEMATICA code here......            
G = (gs*ge)/(A*r^2)
a = (Gamma[1 + m] - Gamma[1 + m, G])
b = ge^k
c = Exp[-ge/(B*e^2)]
p = a*b*c
pp = Integrate[p, {ge, 0, Infinity}]

Comment: Take care : it is the  regularized hypergeometric function

Comment: Ok sir....understood...

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, there are two ways to retrace what happens behind the scenes in Mathematica.

First solution is the usage of the `Trace` command:

```
G = (gs*ge)/(A*r^2)
a = (Gamma[1 + m] - Gamma[1 + m, G])
b = ge^k
c = Exp[-ge/(B*e^2)]
p = a*b*c
Trace[Integrate[p, {ge, 0, Infinity}]]
```

It outputs the following trace:

[image]

Second solution is the step-by-step integeration using the [Rule-based Integrator (Rubi)](https://rulebasedintegration.org/) package:

```
G = (gs*ge)/(A*r^2)
a = (Gamma[1 + m] - Gamma[1 + m, G])
b = ge^k
c = Exp[-ge/(B*e^2)]
p = a*b*c
Get["Rubi`"]
Steps[Int[p, ge]]
```

Here is a screenshot of Mathematica's step-by-step integration (based on Rubi):

[image]

Comment: I tried both ....but its not working in my MATHEMATICA ...

Comment: just a moment - I will add a screenshot. You may send me your working notebook and I will try to add the trace mode.

Comment: Ok... Thank you for your quick reply....How shall I send you my working notebook....

Comment: Ok...Sent the code on your gmail ID...

Comment: I'll check it and post the full answer here in the case I get this working.

Comment: Ok...sure......